# I can't get my Keras classification model to converge

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to train a Keras classification model and I should be getting a loss of less than 0.020 but I'm not. I think my model is configured correctly and so should my data. Can I get some help?

In

```
print(tx2array[:10])
print(toy2array[:10])
```

Out

```
[[1.7245509  1.16666667 0.11537556]
 [1.7245509  1.16666667 0.69931717]
 [0.5748503  1.66666667 0.09230045]
 [0.5748503  1.16666667 0.33670826]
 [0.5748503  1.16666667 0.69931717]
 [1.1497006  0.33333333 1.21968448]
 [0.5748503  0.83333333 0.16482223]
 [1.1497006  1.66666667 0.27548858]
 [0.5748503  0.33333333 2.26512833]
 [1.1497006  1.66666667 0.97951495]]
[[1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0.]]
```

In

```
initializer = keras.initializers.RandomUniform(minval = -1, maxval = 1)

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(16, activation = K.elu, input_shape = [3], kernel_initializer = initializer),
    keras.layers.Dense(32, activation = K.elu, kernel_initializer = initializer),
    keras.layers.Dense(16, activation = K.elu, kernel_initializer = initializer),
    keras.layers.Dense(oy2array.shape[1], activation = 'softmax')
])

model.compile(loss = keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.01), metrics = ['accuracy'])

model_train = model.fit(tx2array, toy2array, epochs = 2000, verbose = 1, validation_data = (vx2array, voy2array))
best_epoch = np.argmin(model_train.history['loss']) + 1
print('Best epoch = ', best_epoch)
print('Smallest loss =', np.min(model_train.history['loss']))
```

Out

```
Best epoch =  1921
Smallest loss = 0.6525248885154724
```

Comment: Why do you think your loss should be as low as you say?

Comment: I'm doing an assignment for my university and that is what's expected for the dataset.